# Как в телеграм боте сделать вызов команды с упором на конкретное слово (неважно какой регистр)?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Например: ПРИВЕТ, Привет, ПрИВет

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text(message):
    if message.text == 'Привет':
        name = f'<b>Привет, <u>{message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}</u>. Я Be to Be bot, задай мне вопрос, например что ты можешь?.</b>'
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, name, parse_mode='html')
```

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Неужели сложно посмотреть на собственный вопрос после публикации? Неужели сложно найти один из 500 ответов на эту тему здесь на сайте?

Answer (score 1):

Переведи все символы слова в нижний регистр с помощью `.lower()`